# installing python library in Virtualenv without pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, virtualenv

I want to install some python's library in some `Virtualenv` but don't want to use `pip` or `easy_install`.
Is it possible to install it by building the source?

Comment: is there any reason on why you do not want to use pip to manage ur packages in virtualenv?

Comment: i don't want to download library for each Virtualenv!

Comment: AFAIK pip caches the downloads - so there should be no reason to start copying files manually.

Comment: without considering downloading libraries, is it possible to install it by building the source??

Comment: @cel One reason, I would want that is that, pip doesn't have the latest version of a package (like `redis==5.0.5`) whereas it is possible to install it using make

Answer (score 1):

Following command should work with activated python environment:

```
$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python setup.py install
```